# remove only the unknown words from a text but leave punctuation and digits

Tags: python, regex, list, punctuation

I have a text in French containing words that are separated by space (e.g répu blique*). I want to remove these separated words from the text and append them into a list while keeping punctuation and digits in the text. My code works for appending the words that are separated but it does not work to keep the digits in the text.

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

import re

with open ('french_text.txt') as tx: 
#opening text containing the separated words
    #stores the text with the separated words
    text = word_tokenize(tx.read().lower()) 


with open ('Fr-dictionary.txt') as fr:  #opens the dictionary
    dic = word_tokenize(fr.read().lower()) #stores the first dictionary

pat=re.compile(r'[.?\-",:]+|\d+')

out_file=open("newtext.txt","w") #defining name of output file
valid_words=[ ] #empty list to append the words checked by the dictionary 
invalid_words=[ ] #empty list to append the errors found

for word in text:
    reg=pat.findall(word)
    if reg is True:
        valid_words.append(word)
    elif word in dic:
        valid_words.append(word)#appending to a list the words checked 
    else:
        invalid_words.append(word) #appending the invalid_words



a=' '.join(valid_words) #converting list into a string

print(a) #print converted list
print(invalid_words) #print errors found

out_file.write(a) #writing the output to a file

out_file.close()
```

so, with this code, my list of errors come with the digits.

`['ments', 'prési', 'répu', 'blique', 'diri', 'geants', '»', 'grand-est', 'elysée', 'emmanuel', 'macron', 'sncf', 'pepy', 'montparnasse', '1er', '2017.', 'geoffroy', 'hasselt', 'afp', 's', 'empare', 'sncf', 'grand-est', '26', 'elysée', 'emmanuel', 'macron', 'sncf', 'saint-dié', 'epinal', '23', '2018', 'etat', 's', 'vosges', '2018']`

I think the problem is with the regular expression. Any suggestions? Thank you!!

Comment: It is easier to show sample text and what your regex does to it. This is better, because nobody know's what's in your file or how you are using it.

Comment: In other words, 'what's your input, and what is your desired output?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your if statement where you check `reg is True`. You should not use the `is` operator with `True` to check if the result of `pat.findall(word)` was positive (i.e. you had a matching word).

You can do this instead:

```
for word in text:
    if pat.match(word):
        valid_words.append(word)
    elif word in dic:
        valid_words.append(word)#appending to a list the words checked 
    else:
        invalid_words.append(word) #appending the invalid_words
```

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat user**: this is actually a complex problem, because it all depends on what we define to be a word:

- is `l’Académie` a single word, how about `j’eus` ?
- is `gallo-romanes` a single word, or `c'est-à-dire`?
- how about `J.-C.`?
- and `xiv(e)` (with superscript, as in 14 siecle)?
- and then `QDN` or `QQ1` or `LOL`?

Here's a **direct solution**, that's summarised as:

1. break up text into "words" and "non-words" (punctuation, spaces)
2. validate "words" against a dictionary

```py
# Adjust this to your locale
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

text = "foo bar, baz"

while True:
    m = WORD.search(text)
    if not m:
        if text:
            print(f"punctuation: {text!r}")
        break
    start, end = m.span()
    punctuation = text[:start]
    word = text[start:end]
    text = text[end:]
    if punctuation:
        print(f"punctuation: {punctuation!r}")
    print(f"possible word: {word!r}")

possible word: 'foo'
punctuation: ' '
possible word: 'bar'
punctuation: ', '
possible word: 'baz'
```

I get a feeling that you are trying to deal with intentionally misspelt / broken up words, e.g. if someone is trying to get around forum blacklist rules or speech analysis.

Then, a **better approach** would be:

1. identify what might be a "word" or "non-word" using a dictionary
2. then break up the text

If the original text was made to evade computers but be readable by humans, your best bet would be ML/AI, most likely a neural network, like RNN's used to identify objects in images.

Comment: I've found already the solution to all the cases you have pointed out. Thanks!!